# building a voice recorder using html5 and javascript

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, html5-audio

I want to build a voice recorder using HTML5 same as one found in gitHub JSSoundecorder, but what I want is for the user to be able to choose the file format before recording the voice.I can do this using ffmpeg. In other words the user must be able to select the audio format by check box (mp3,wma,pcm) and in the background code, the .wav file usually created by the program instead of displaying it, it should be converted by the format selected then displayed in the new format.this is the ffmpeg code we can use ,but I don't know how to get the .wav audio file to convert it and show it.please if someone have ideas,or if can find demos I have been looking for weeks.this is the ffmpeg code:

```
   var fileName;
   var fileBuffer;

   function timeToSeconds(time) {
      var parts = time.split(":");
      return parseFloat(parts[0]) * 60 * 60 + parseFloat(parts[1]) * 60 + parseFloat(parts[2]) + parseFloat("0." + parts[3]);
  }

  // create ffmpeg worker
  function getFFMPEGWorker() {
      // regexps for extracting time from ffmpeg logs
      var durationRegexp = /Duration: (.*?), /
      var timeRegexp = /time=(.*?) /;
      var duration;

      var ffmpegWorker = new Worker('worker.js');
      var durationLine;
      ffmpegWorker.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
          var message = event.data;
          console.log(message.type);
          if (message.type === "ready" && window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
              // script loaded, hide loader
              $('#loading').hide();
          } else if (message.type == "stdout") {
              console.log(message.data);
          } else if (message.type == "stderr") {
              console.log(message.data);
              // try to extract duration
              if (durationRegexp.exec(message.data)) {
                  duration = timeToSeconds(durationRegexp.exec(message.data)[1]);
              }
              // try to extract time
              if (timeRegexp.exec(message.data)) {
                  var time = timeToSeconds(timeRegexp.exec(message.data)[1]);
                  if (duration) {
                      $("#progress").text("Progress: " + Math.floor(time / duration * 100) + "%");
                      $("#progress").show();
                  }
              }
          } else if (message.type == "done") {
              var code = message.data.code;

             console.log(message.data);
              var outFileNames = Object.keys(message.data.outputFiles);

              console.log(outFileNames);
              if (code == 0 && outFileNames.length) {
                  var outFileName = outFileNames[0];

                  var outFileBuffer = message.data.outputFiles[outFileName];

                  var src = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([outFileBuffer]));

                  $("#downloadLink").attr('href', src);
                  $("#download").show();
              } else {
                  $("#error").show();
              }
              $("#converting").hide();
              $("#progress").hide();
          }
      }, false);
      return ffmpegWorker;
   }

   // create ffmpeg worker
   var ffmpegWorker = getFFMPEGWorker();
   var ffmpegRunning = false;

   $('#convert').click(function() {
      // terminate existing worker
      if (ffmpegRunning) {
          ffmpegWorker.terminate();
          ffmpegWorker = getFFMPEGWorker();
      }
      ffmpegRunning = true;

      // display converting animation
      $("#converting").show();
      $("#error").hide();

      // hide download div
      $("#download").hide();

      // change download file name
      var fileNameExt = fileName.substr(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

      var outFileName = fileName.substr(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.')) + "." + getOutFormat();

        $("#downloadLink").attr("download", outFileName);
      $("#downloadLink").text(outFileName);

      var arguments = [];
      arguments.push("-i");
      arguments.push(fileName);

      arguments.push("-b:a");
      arguments.push(getBitrate());

      switch (getOutFormat()) {
          case "mp3":
              arguments.push("-acodec");
              arguments.push("libmp3lame");
              arguments.push("out.mp3");
              break;

          case "wma":
              arguments.push("-acodec");
              arguments.push("wmav1");
              arguments.push("out.asf");
              break;

          case "pcm":
              arguments.push("-f");
              arguments.push("s16le");
              arguments.push("-acodec");
              arguments.push("pcm_s16le");
              arguments.push("out.pcm");
      }

      ffmpegWorker.postMessage({

          type: "command",
          arguments: arguments,
          files: [
              {
                  "name": fileName,
                  "buffer": fileBuffer
              }
          ]

      });
  });

  function getOutFormat() {
      return $('input[name=format]:checked').val();
  }

  function getBitrate() {
      return $('input[name=bitrate]:checked').val();
  }

  // disable conversion at start
  $('#convert').attr('disabled', 'true');

  function readInputFile(file) {
      // disable conversion for the time of file loading
      $('#convert').attr('disabled', 'true');

      // load file content
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
          $('#convert').removeAttr('disabled');
          fileName = file.name;
        console.log(fileName);
          fileBuffer = e.target.result;
      }
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

  }

  // reset file selector at start
  function resetInputFile() {
      $("#inFile").wrap('<form>').closest('form').get(0).reset();
      $("#inFile").unwrap();
  }
  resetInputFile();

  function handleFileSelect(event) {
      var files = event.target.files; // FileList object
  console.log(files);
      // files is a FileList of File objects. display first file name
      file = files[0];
      console.log(file);
      if (file) {
          $("#drop").text("Drop file here");
          readInputFile(file);


      }
  }


  // setup input file listeners

  document.getElementById('inFile').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```